# Software to design/generate/customize a map for a Fantasy World

Tags: windows, gratis, images

I'm trying to do some fantasy worldbuilding, and I'm at the point where I need a map for my world. It would be great to be able to control terrain, such as mountains, rivers, and such, as well as city locations and political borders.

I am not against using a non-dedicated image editing program, if it contains features that would make map-making easier.

In the past, I've always drawn maps on paper, scanned them, and traced them, so I was hoping that there was an easier process that might make it easier to make changes as I'm working.

Comment: well it is not free, but neverless: [campaing cartographer](https://www.profantasy.com/products/cc3.asp)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought when reading your question was to use a 3d imaging program like [Blender](//Blender.org/),  and when searching for [making terrain models program](//Google.com/search?q=making+terrain+models+programs), I found this Blender tutorial: [Blender 3d: Noob to Pro/Making Landscapes with heightmaps heightmaps](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Making_Landscapes_with_heightmaps).  I also found this list of [artificial terrain tools & software packages](http://vterrain.org/Packages/Artificial/) which might be a bit old,  but should get you going.

Comment: I don't think user15947 is looking for a 3d modeling program. It sounds like he is looking for a 2d cartography solution.

Comment: Hard to say, and he hasn't commented either.  And whilst he says he had drawn them by hand (suggesting 2d), he also says to control terrain, like mountains (suggesting 3d). Anyway the proposed solution does also provide for printing 2d maps.